# Kafka exporter for latest kafka (kafka 17)

Tags: apache-kafka, kubernetes-helm, monitoring, kafka-exporter

I want to add monitoring of my kafka.

I've found product named kafka exporter which depends on 14.9.3.  I use kafka 17(https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/kafka/17.0.0) and it doesn't work with latest kafka exporter(https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/prometheus-community/prometheus-kafka-exporter, version: 1.6.0) because of version incompatibility. I investigated the issue and found out that it is because kafka exporter can't work with kafka 17. I tried to downgrade kafka to to 14.9.3 and problem disappeared.

So my question is: how to monitor Kafka 17 ?

Comment: "Kafka 17" or "Kafka 14.9.3" Aren't real versions of Kafka. The exporter only relies on Java, so did you mean **Java** 17?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I mean kaka helm chart version

Comment: https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/kafka/17.0.0

Comment: Okay, and when you say "exporter doesn't work", is there a specific error from k8s or the exporter pods that you get?

Comment: Maybe you should ask/report your issue here as well https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+kafka

Comment: Or you can use [Strimzi Operator](https://strimzi.io/blog/2019/10/14/improving-prometheus-metrics/), which offers that exporter.